# Remove only y-axis line from chat drawn using chart.js 1.0.2

Tags: javascript, chart.js

How to remove only y-axis from chart, 
I am using Chart.js version 1.0.2 and trying to remove using following code.

`var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
            scales: {
               yAxes: [{
                   display: false
               }]},
            responsive: true
        });`

Using above code not able to remove / hide it.
Is there any way to remove / hide only y-axis

Answer (score 0):

You should create the options hash before render your chart. Check the example bellow:

```
var options = {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        display: false
      }]
    }

var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, { type: 'line', data: data, options: options});
```

more about x and y axis cfg: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/